# Datetime is not inserted in table when executing the query through Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, datetime, jakarta-ee

I am using MySQL 5.5 and I am inserting `datetime` into my table through Java, using the query:

```
INSERT INTO player_sale(transaction_id,player_id,game_id,game_type_id,ticket_nbr,mrp_amt,deduct_from_bonus,deduct_from_deposit,deduct_from_winning,good_cause_amt,vat_amt,taxable_sale,transaction_date,is_cancel) VALUES(48160,1001501,1,2,0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,'2015-07-09 18:45:01','N');
```

but the entry inserted is `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in the `transaction_date` column.

In addition to it, when I am executing the above query, through the query browser interface of MySQL, the correct datetime is inserted . The datatype of `transacion_date` is `datetime`.

I have dug out a lot of web, but I couldn't find the answer regarding the same.

```
I used the following java code :
try{    
    Timestamp transactionDate = new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    String query="INSERT INTO player_sale(transaction_id,player_id,game_id,game_type_id,ticket_nbr,mrp_amt,deduct_from_bonus,
              deduct_from_deposit,deduct_from_winning,good_cause_amt,vat_amt,taxable_sale,transaction_date,is_cancel) 
              VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
    PreparedStatement pt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    pt.setLong(1, 1);
    pt.setLong(2, 110021);
    pt.setInt(3, 1);
    pt.setInt(4, 1);
    pt.setLong(5, 12345678);
    pt.setDouble(6, 10.00);
    pt.setDouble(7, 20.00);
    pt.setDouble(8,30.00);
    pt.setDouble(9, 40.00);
    pt.setDouble(10, 10.00);
    pt.setDouble(11, 2.00);
    pt.setDouble(12, 1.00);
    pt.setTimestamp(13, transactionDate);
    pt.setString(14, "N");
    pstmt.executeUpdate();          
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: How are you sending the query? You may want to consider using a `PreparedStatement`, since that allows you to simply insert a `java.sql.Date` which will avoid such problems while also being safer than a regular `Statement`

Comment: Please show us the java code, and include some hard evidence that the datetime value that you are using is *really* '2015-07-09 18:45:01'.  (IME - the most likely explanation is that the code is not doing what you think it is doing.)

Comment: try use str_to_date('2015-07-09 18:45:01', '%Y-%m-%d %T') instead of '2015-07-09 18:45:01' in your query 

INSERT INTO player_sale(transaction_id,player_id,game_id,game_type_id,ticket_nbr,mrp_amt,deduct_from_bonus,deduct_from_deposit,deduct_from_winning,good_cause_amt,vat_amt,taxable_sale,transaction_date,is_cancel) VALUES(48160,1001501,1,2,0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,str_to_date('2015-07-09 18:45:01', '%Y-%m-%d %T'),'N');